# jquery voting system images are not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to implement a voting system similar to stackoverflow and I have something similar to this:

Html:

```
<div id="answer_595" class="answer">
  <img src="vote_up.png" class="vote up">
  <div class="score">0</div>
  <img src="vote_down.png" class="vote down">
  Blah blah blah this is my answer.
</div>

<div id="answer_596" class="answer">
  <img src="vote_up.png" class="vote up">
  <div class="score">0</div>
  <img src="vote_down.png" class="vote down">
  Blah blah blah this is my other answer.
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.answer img.vote').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).parents('div.answer').attr('id').split('_')[1];
        var vote_type = $(this).hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down';
        if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $.post('/vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type}, function(json) {
                if(json.success == 'success') {
                    $('#answer_' + id)
                     .find('img.' + vote_type)
                     .attr('src', 'vote_' + vote_type + '_selected.png')
                     .addClass('selected');
                    $('div.score', '#answer_' + id).html(json.score);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.post('/remove_vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type}, function(json) {
                if(json.success == 'success') {
                    $('#answer_' + id)
                     .find('img.' + vote_type);
                     .attr('src', 'vote_' + vote_type + '.png')
                     .removeClass('selected');
                    $('div.score', '#answer_' + id).html(json.score);
                }
            });                
        }
    });
});
```

Th images are not clickable. how come?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, the images are "not clickable"?  Surely you *can* click on them.  What happens when you do?  Have you used any sort of debugger to check whether your handler is called?

Comment: as in when you hover them no pointer shows...like hovering a hyperlink, but more importantly it doesnt seem as the jquery code is not being invoked when it i do click on the image.

Comment: for the pointer, you just need `img.vote { cursor: pointer; }` in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your check seems backwards, you have:

```
if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
```

This (at least seems to be) checking if it *already* has a vote, so it should be the reverse check given the rest of your code...currently you would be calling `/remove_vote/` on the first click (when there hasn't been a vote cast, at least not that direction), so just do:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
```

Also, something to consider is that since you already have the `<img>` you clicked on, you can just keep a reference to it, no need to go and find it again, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('div.answer img.vote').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('div.answer').attr('id').split('_').pop(),
      vote_type = $(this).hasClass('up') ? 'up' : 'down',
      self = this;
    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $.post('/vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type}, function(json) {
        if(json.success == 'success') {
          self.src = 'vote_' + vote_type + '_selected.png';
          $(self).addClass('selected').siblings('div.score').html(json.score);
        } else { alert("Oh @#$% gremlins!"); }
      });
    } else {
      $.post('/remove_vote/', {id: id, type: vote_type}, function(json) {
        if(json.success == 'success') {
          self.src = 'vote_' + vote_type + '.png';
          $(self).removeClass('selected').siblings('div.score').html(json.score);
        } else { alert("Oh @#$% gremlins!"); }
      });                
    }
  });
});
```

Also, for cases with more than a few answers, it would be better to use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), by replacing this:

```
$('div.answer img.vote').click(function() {
```

With this:

```
$('#answerContainer').delegate('div.answer img.vote', 'click', function() {
```

Comment: I Have updated, but the jquery code still doesnt seem to be getting invoked when i click on the images.

Comment: @raklos - are the elements created dynamically, after the page loads?  Also, try sticking a simple `alert()` in there to see if it's getting called.

Comment: Thanks, would answercontainer be a div with id=answerContainer around every answer?

Comment: @raklos - Almost, it would be a single `<div>` around *all* the  answers :)

Comment: Hey, I've got this working, but not with the "self" variable you suggested for improvemnt. is there something wrong above? thanks